# Change Amiga Shell keyboard layout in Workbench 1.3

Tags: amiga, amiga-shell, amiga-500, amiga-workbench-1.3

I'm using Workbench 1.3 in Amiga 500.

I managed to change the Spanish keyboard in "SetMap", as shown in the following figure:

[image: Screenshot of Configuration]

And I can write text with special spanish characters (ñ,ç,ó,á,...) from regular application like NotePad:

[image: Screenshot with Spanish text]

But when I try to use AmigaShell, keyboard layout is in USA key-map always, and its very difficult to write in Spanish Keyboard.

How I could change Amiga Shell Key Layout to Spanish Key Layout?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alright, you seem to already have the correct keymap file in `DEVS:keymaps/`, as you seem to be able to use the Keymap in Workbench programs. That's good (otherwise you would have had to copy it from `"Extras 1.3:Devs/keymaps"` to `DEVS:keymaps/`).

Now open your Workbench disk and start the `Shell`. In the Shell, type:

```
ed S:Startup-Sequence
```

This will bring up a text editor showing the Amiga startup script (similar in vein to MS-DOS' autoexec.bat). In there look for a line similar to this:

```
SYS:System/SetMap usa1
```

Change the `usa1` or whatever keymap it loads to `e`. Make very sure that you don't change anything else or you might have a hard time to fix it next time you try to boot Workbench. Now press **Esc**, which will bring you into command mode. You will see a lone `*` at the beginning of the bottom line of the editor after which you can enter commands. Type `x` and press the **Enter** key, which will save the changed file and exit the editor.

Next time you boot up Workbench it should have changed the CLI and Shell keymap to Español.

In case you don't find a line with `Setmap` in the `Startup-Sequence`, you will need to insert it there yourself. I would suggest somewhere before `LoadWB`. Press Enter to create a new empty line and put the following command there:

```
SYS:System/SetMap e
```

Then perform the same saving as above (**Esc**, then `x`, then **Enter**) and reboot.

Comment: It's useful to run `SYS:System/SetMap e` in the shell (or in my case I needed to fix it to `usa1` when it was `i` in the startup sequence) before trying to use `ed`, so then your mapping of choice will be in effect while making edits to the startup.  Notepad also works instead of ed.